# Unavailable_shards_exception, reason: primary shard is not active

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to send data from filebeat-->logstash-->Elasticsearch Cluster-->kibana.

I have a cluster with 3 nodes. 2 are master eligible nodes and 1 is client node.
I have checked the health of the cluster using the below command,

**curl -XGET "http://132.186.102.61:9200/_cluster/state?pretty"**
I can see the output properly with elected master.

When the filebeat pushes data to logstash, i see the following error,
 logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - retrying failed action with response code: 503 ({"type"=>"unavailable_shards_exception", "reason"=>"[logstash-2017.06.05][1] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[logstash-2017.06.05][1]] containing [3] requests]"})

this is my logstash.conf,

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5043"
        #ssl => true
        #ssl_certificate_authorities => "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/testca/cacert.pem"
        #ssl_certificate => "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/server/cert.pem"
        #ssl_key => "D:/Softwares/ELK/ELK_SSL_Certificates/server/pkcs8.key"
        #ssl_key_passphrase => "MySecretPassword"
        #ssl_verify_mode => "force_peer"
    }
}
filter{
    grok
    {
        match => {"message" =>"%{IP:client} %{NUMBER:duration} %{GREEDYDATA:messageFromClient}"}
    }
}

#filter{
#if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
#        drop { }
#  }
#}
output {
    elasticsearch {hosts => ["132.186.189.127:9200","132.186.102.61:9200","132.186.102.43:9200"]}
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

May i please know the reason for this issue.

Comment: i think i found the issue. Before this cluster, i had another cluster with 4 nodes. 3 master eligible and 1 client node. 
Now for the new cluster which i am using, i am not using that 4th node which was master eligible. And that 4th node is down as well.

I feel that 4th node is holding some data to which the other nodes has some pointers to it. Since that 4th node is down, the 
other old nodes which i am using in the new cluster is not able to get the data. THats the reason i am getting this exception.

i cleared the data folder from the nodes and it started working fine.

Comment: But the question still remains,

What if one of the master eligible nodes goes down . What will happen to the data stored in that node.